# Subir una imagen con Alamofire

Tags: imagen, fileupload, alamofire

Deseo enviar una imagen que ha sido capturada en un lienzo tipo lienzo en IOS, no deseo recodificarla a BASE64, deseo enviarla como "archivo".

Intenté usar la fuente `Alamofire.upload`, sin embargo me mostró el siguiente error:

> "No se puede invocar 'anexar' con una lista de argumentos de tipo
>   '(UIImage, withName: String)'"

Luego hice las modificaciones y el siguiente código me manda el error:

> "El tipo de expresión es ambiguo sin más contexto"

El código utilizado es el siguiente:

```
func uploadMultiformData1 () {

    //variables
    let usuario = "alfred"
    let datosAdd = "otros datos"
    //endRegion

    //parameters
    let parametros =
        [
            "idUsuario": usuario,
            "aditionalData": datosAdd
            ] as [String : AnyObject]

    //endRegion
// la imagen proviene de: @IBOutlet weak var mainImageView: UIImageView!

    let image = mainImageView.image
    let imageData = image!.pngData()

    // CREATE AND SEND REQUEST ----------

    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
        for (key, item) in parametros {
            multipartFormData.append(item.data(using:.utf8)!, withName: key)
        }

        multipartFormData.append(imageData!, withName: "image", fileName: "swift_file.jpeg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
    }, to:url)
    { (result) in
        switch result {
        case .success(let upload, _, _):

            upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (Progress) in
                print("Upload Progress: \(Progress.fractionCompleted)")
            })

            upload.responseJSON { response in
                //self.delegate?.showSuccessAlert()
                print(response.request)  // original URL request
                print(response.response) // URL response
                print(response.data)     // server data
                print(response.result)   // result of response serialization
                //                        self.showSuccesAlert()
                //self.removeImage("frame", fileExtension: "txt")
                if let JSON = response.result.value {
                    print("JSON: \(JSON)")
                }
            }

        case .failure(let encodingError):
            //self.delegate?.showFailAlert()
            print(encodingError)
        }

    }

}
```

El resultado requerido es:

1. Tomar la imagen que ya está dibujando el usuario en el `ImageView`
2. Adjuntarla al envio en el tipo POST
3. El servidor responde en JSON